# Unable to install MS SQL Server due to missing DLL, how do I find and install this DLL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I tried to install sql server 2017 on windows server 2019 but the following error appeared to me:

> There is a Problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this installation to complete could not be run. Contact you support personnel or package vendor.

Here are the solutions that I have tried that did not work!

- Update Windows
- Uninstall then reinstall SQL Server 2017
- Completely change installable "another SQL Server 2017, SQL Server 2014, SQL Server 2019".
- I tried to install the English version
- I checked the administrator permissions on the file `c:/windows/utilisateur/appdata/local/temp`, it has total control.
- I checked the administrator permissions on registry `editor/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/CurrentControlSet/services/msiserver/security`, it has total control.
- I copied the file dll (`sqlncli11.dll`) into syswow64 and system32.
- I also checked the system files with the command sfc/scannow  to see if there are any corrupt files.
- And when I install I always run as administrator.

Comment: How was there anything to **uninstall** if the initial installation failed? (re: "*Uninstall then reinstall SQL Server 2017*")

Comment: Yes, there are Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server, Microsoft OLE DB Driver 17 for SQL Server and Microsoft VSS Writer for SQL Server 2017 !! ie: all that is related to SQL server that I find in the programs and functionalities. Because the installation hangs in the middle of the execution!

Comment: Your question mentions a "missing DLL", but the error message in fact says that the DLL "could not be run", which is a different problem. Did you check the [setup logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/view-and-read-sql-server-setup-log-files?view=sql-server-ver15) for details?

Answer (score 1):

Even I had the same issue and tried all the steps but it didn't work. I followed the below link and it worked for me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49634848

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).